# Would using gelatin as a fining agent for clarifying beer render the beer not kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

As per the answer in this question [Is Guinness Beer no longer kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27165/is-guinness-beer-no-longer-kosher?rq=1)

that isinglass which is not intended to stay in the beer does not pose a kashrus concern then according to this logic would any fining agent be permitted to be used to clarify beer including gelatin?

Does the person adding the fining agent being Jewish or not have any impact on the use of fining agents?

Comment: What is the difference between gelatin (this question) or collagen from non-kosher fish (the other question)? If no differences aren't these duplicates? Is the fining agent staying or not in the glass? (sorry most of us are not beer experts here)

Comment: when the subject of fining agents is discussed in halacha the example I am familiar with is isinglass. Since this is a non kosher fish I would assume that any fining agent from a non kosher animal would be given the same treatment, however, I do not know for certain and this is why I asked. Perhaps someone that knows the teshuva of the nodeh ben yehuda could say so specifically that this can be applied to other fining agents or not?

Comment: About 45 years ago I worked in a research centre on a project to use soluble eucollagen as a fining agent for beer. This was derived from cattle hide. Further hydrolysis would have converted this into gelatin. Obviously the original cattle hide is not kosher. Whether the treatment to break down the material would change its status is a matter for an orthodox psak halacha, and without one one assumes it retains its status as non-kosher.